# How to update values in Python's dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

My dictionary looks like below, and I am following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40065381/finding-and-replacing-a-value-in-a-python-dictionary) to update the values in "Column_Type" key. Bascially, I would like to replace values "String" with "VARCHAR(256)", DATE with "NUMBER (4,0)", Int with "NUMBER" and Numeric with "Number". Whenever I run below code, my values are not getting updated to my dictionary.My desired output for updated dictionary is as below

Please note: The location of column_types might vary as well. For ex: Column_type[String] currently is at position 1, but It might be at position 3 later on .

```
{'Column_name': ['Name', 'Salary', 'Date', 'Phone'], 'Column_Type': ['String', 'Numeric', 'Date', 'Int']}
```

**Code:**

```
for key1, key2 in my_dict.items():
    if key2== 'String':
        my_dict[key2] = "VARCHAR(256)"
print(my_dict)
```

**Desired Output:**

```
{'Column_name': ['Name', 'Salary', 'Date', 'Phone'], 'Column_Type': ['VARCHAR(256)', 'NUMBER', 'NUMBER(4,0)', 'NUMBER']}
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: `items()` returns a tuple of `key, value`.  So `key2` would be the entire column list.  It will never equal "String".

Comment: @debugger..updated  the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, your keys are `"Column_Name"` and `Column_Type"`. There is *no* key named "String" in your dict. Both values in your dict are of type `list` so neither are equal to the string `String` either.

What you want is to replace a specific value in a list.

Try like this:

```py
for index, value in enumerate(my_dict["Column_Type"]):
    if value == "String":
        my_dict["Column_Type"][index] = "VARCHAR(256)"
```

This replaces the value in the `list`, **not** the dict. That is what you want.

If you need to replace multiple values you can use a dict, like @Jeremy suggested:

```py
type_strs = {
    'String': 'VARCHAR(256)',
    'Numeric': 'NUMBER',
    'Date': 'NUMBER(4,0)',
    'Int': 'NUMBER'
}

for index, value in enumerate(my_dict["Column_Type"]):
    my_dict["Column_Type"][index] = type_strs.get(value, value)
```

Here, the `.get()` function on a dict returns the value corresponding to the key given by the first argument, or the second argument if no such key exists.

Comment: Thank you! I tried your suggested code and seems like it replaced entire "Column_type" with VARCHAR(256). The output that I received running above code is : {'Column_name': ['Name', 'Salary', 'Date', 'Phone'], 'Column_Type': 'VARCHAR(256)'}

Comment: My answer was incorrect at first, I updated it since

Comment: Thank you @mousetail & Jeremy and other SO users. Found the solution!!

Answer (score 3):

```
type_strs = {
    'String': 'VARCHAR(256)',
    'Numeric': 'NUMBER',
    'Date': 'NUMBER(4,0)',
    'Int': 'NUMBER'
}
my_dict['Column_Type'] = [type_strs[t] for t in my_dict['Column_Type']]
```

I would recommend a dictionary instead of if statements for translating the type strings

Comment: Thank you @Jeremy, appreciate your help! loved your approach.

Answer (score 2):

Your are in this line comparing a list with an element of this list `if key2== 'String'`:

`key2` when you are traveling the variable contains the next `['String', 'Numeric', 'Date', 'Int']`, so you will need to join to this value of the array for compare. You can do it with a `for` cycle

The program is the next:

```
my_dict={'Column_name': ['Name', 'Salary', 'Date', 'Phone'], 'Column_Type': ['String', 'Numeric', 'Date', 'Int']}

# We create this variable to save the position of the element
position=0

# We travel to the dictionary
for i in my_dict['Column_Type']:

    # If the variable is equal to the string
    if i == 'String':

        # We assign the new information to the variable
        my_dict['Column_Type'][position]="VARCHAR(256)"

    #And add one to the position
    position+=1
    
print(my_dict)
```

**Output**

```
{'Column_name': ['Name', 'Salary', 'Date', 'Phone'], 'Column_Type': ['VARCHAR(256)', 'Numeric', 'Date', 'Int']}
```

Comment: It's more concise to use `enumerate` rather than to keep a separate variable for the position, otherwise a good answer

Comment: This answer could be improved slightly by using `enumerate` to iterate over the index (`position` in your code) and value (`i` in your code) at the same time

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I still learning but I love to help if i can

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list.update(val1, val2)`

example:

```
# Dictionary of strings to ints
word_freq = {
    "Hello": 56,
    "at": 23,
    "test": 43,
    "this": 43
}
# Adding a new key value pair
word_freq.update({'before': 23})
print(word_freq)
```

Comment: So, this isn't what the question is asking, and `my_dict.update({"key": "value"})` is not the idiomatic way of udpating a single key-value, you should just use `my_dict[key] = value`